# Extracting images from pptx with apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, xslf

I'm trying to extract slides from a `ppt` file with Apache POI, there is no problem in that, but now I intend to open `pptx` files and do the same, does anyone knows how to??

this is the code to extract images from `ppt` files:

```
public ImageIcon display() throws JPresentationException { 

    Background background; 
    background = slides[current].getBackground(); 
    Fill f = background.getFill(); 
    Color color = f.getForegroundColor(); 
    Dimension dimension = ppt.getPageSize(); 
    shapes = slides[current].getShapes(); 
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(dimension.width, dimension.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
    Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics(); 
    graphics.setPaint(color); 
    graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, dimension.width, dimension.height)); 
    slides[current].draw(graphics); 
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img); 

    return icon; 
}
```

Comment: your question sounded strange but I think it makes sense if you really mean you can do this with a ppt file.  I edited your answer but rollback my changes if this is not correct.

Comment: I think *pptx* is suitable, most of us have office 2007 now.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can refer to some [example code](https://poi.apache.org/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html) from the POI project itself
below is what you should be looking for; Hope this helps;

```
private ImageIcon generateFromPPTX(int index) {
    ImageIcon icon = null;
    XMLSlideShow slideShowPPTX = null;
    FileInputStream pptInputStream = null;
    XSLFSlide [] allSlides = null;
    XSLFSlide singleSlide = null;
    BufferedImage memoryImage = null;
    Graphics2D graphics = null;
    try{
        pptInputStream = new FileInputStream("somepptx-file.pptx");
        slideShowPPTX = new XMLSlideShow(pptInputStream);
        allSlides = slideShowPPTX.getSlides();
        if(allSlides == null || allSlides.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Empty presentation!");
            return null;
        }

        singleSlide = allSlides [index];
        memoryImage = new BufferedImage(slideShowPPTX.getPageSize().width, slideShowPPTX.getPageSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        graphics = memoryImage.createGraphics();
        // Only few rendering hints set but you can set as many as you need depending on your need
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        singleSlide.draw(graphics);
        icon = new ImageIcon(memoryImage);
    }
    catch(IOException exception){
        System.err.println("Input/output Exception:");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        slideShowPPTX = null;
        allSlides = null;
        singleSlide = null;
        memoryImage = null;
        graphics = null;
        if(pptInputStream != null){
            try {
                pptInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            pptInputStream = null;
        }
    }
    return icon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to do it in VBS, Maybe you can convert :

```
Sub SaveAllPictures()
    Dim ap As Presentation: Set ap = ActivePresentation
    Dim savePath As String
    savePath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\files\"
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sl As Slide
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sl In ap.Slides
        For Each sh In sl.Shapes
            If sh.Type = msoPicture Then
                sh.Export PathName:=savePath & sh.Name & CStr(i) & ".png", Filter:=ppShapeFormatPNG
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```